# OnPageStarted is never used locally

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm having a problem here. The eclipse says that my method "onPageStarted" is never used locally.

Running the app, the method "onPageFinished" is called, but the "onPageStarted" is not called at all.

Does anyone have any clue?

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SiteActivityClient(){
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url){         
   }
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you're missing an argument, thus creating a new method instead of implementing one from WebViewClient.

```
public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
```

So you're missing `Bitmap favicon`

Comment: Using @Override (you should add those too yeah) would indeed have given you an error about this :)